# Local Time Zone in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, timezone

Needs to create a Rails App where I want to get the time in local time Zone i.e. if the location is **Delhi** the time zone should be **IST** and if the the location is **San Fransisco** the time zone should be **PDT**.

How to accomplish this in ruby on rails?

P.S. One line code that can set the time zone automatically according to the location.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

try this `Time.now.getlocal.zone`

Comment: This gives me the local zone. I want that if a person sitting in New Delhi accesses my app then he gets to see the time in "IST" and if a person is sitting in SanFransisco he gets to see the time in "PST".. What is the configuration i need to make in my app to achieve this?

Comment: `Time.now.zone` also works, the `getlocal()` method is used to get time to the given utc offset. Documentation: https://apidock.com/ruby/Time/getlocal

Answer (score 3):

If you need the Olson time zone (because three-letter time zones are ambiguous, as are GMT offsets), it looks like there's no way to do it in pure Ruby/Rails. Ruby will only provide the short code (basically via `date +%Z`), and Rails uses the time zone of its configuration (default: UTC).

That said, [shelling out can be made to work](https://gist.github.com/numist/f34cb150e337a8b948d9) in combination with [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12523283/2002206):

```
def get_local_timezone_str
  # Yes, this is actually a shell script…
  olsontz = `if [ -f /etc/timezone ]; then
    cat /etc/timezone
  elif [ -h /etc/localtime ]; then
    readlink /etc/localtime | sed "s/\\/usr\\/share\\/zoneinfo\\///"
  else
    checksum=\`md5sum /etc/localtime | cut -d' ' -f1\`
    find /usr/share/zoneinfo/ -type f -exec md5sum {} \\; | grep "^$checksum" | sed "s/.*\\/usr\\/share\\/zoneinfo\\///" | head -n 1
  fi`.chomp

  # …and it almost certainly won't work with Windows or weird *nixes
  throw "Olson time zone could not be determined" if olsontz.nil? || olsontz.empty?
  return olsontz
end
```