# Getting the Canonical Time Zone name in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, time, timezone

Is there a way of getting the Canonical Time Zone name from a Linux shell script?  for example, if my configured time zone is PDT, then I would like to get "America/Los_Angeles".

I know I could get from the symbolic link /etc/localtime if it were configured, but as it might not be configured in all servers I cannot rely on that one.
On the other hand, I can get the short time zone name with the command date +%Z, but I still need the canonical name.

Is there a way to either get the canonical name of the current time zone or transform the time zone gotten with the date +%Z command, even if the symbolic link /etc/localtime is not set?

Comment: I would say 'PDT' is closer to a canonical name, while 'America/Los_Angeles' is just a descriptive label to help map a location to the correct timezone.

Comment: I don't think this is possible; a single abbreviation, even if expanded unambiguously (e.g. to "Pacific Daylight Time"), can have multiple corresponding TZ-database entries. For example, PDT is not only `America/Los_Angeles`, but also `America/Dawson`, `America/Ensenada`, `America/Sitka`, `America/Tijuana`, `America/Vancouver`, `America/Whitehorse`, and `US/Pacific`. (In fact, if you hadn't specified that you wanted `America/Los_Angeles`, I would have assumed you wanted `US/Pacific`.)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is more complicated than it sounds. Most linux distributions do it differently so there is no 100% reliable way to get the Olson TZ name.

Below is the heuristic that I have used in the past:

1. First check /etc/timezone, if it exists use it.
2. Next check if /etc/localtime is a symlink to the timezone database
3. Otherwise find a file in /usr/share/zoneinfo with the same content
   as the file /etc/localtime

Untested example code:

```
if [ -f /etc/timezone ]; then
  OLSONTZ=`cat /etc/timezone`
elif [ -h /etc/localtime ]; then
  OLSONTZ=`readlink /etc/localtime | sed "s/\/usr\/share\/zoneinfo\///"`
else
  checksum=`md5sum /etc/localtime | cut -d' ' -f1`
  OLSONTZ=`find /usr/share/zoneinfo/ -type f -exec md5sum {} \; | grep "^$checksum" | sed "s/.*\/usr\/share\/zoneinfo\///" | head -n 1`
fi

echo $OLSONTZ
```

Note that this quick example does not handle the case where multiple TZ names match the given file (when looking in /usr/share/zoneinfo). Disambiguating the appropriate TZ name will depend on your application.

-nick

Comment: Well, it's not exactly what i was looking for, but it will work.  Thanks :)

Comment: I used this rather than using md5 and also prevent the match in the posixrules file: `find /usr/share/zoneinfo -type f ! -name 'posixrules' -exec cmp -s {} /etc/localtime \; -print | sed -e 's@.*/zoneinfo/@@' | head -n1`

Comment: I found that the `Etc` directories contained only numeric timezones, so I excluded them from @user9645's  `find`:  `! -regex ".*/Etc/.*"`

Comment: for OSX you should use `/var/db/timezone/zoneinfo/` instead `/usr/share/zoneinfo/`