# Ruby: Getting the configured region on RedHat/CentOS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails application running on a CentOS 7 machine. I would like to read the system-configured region (Olson time zone) into a string (e.g. 'Europe/Stockholm', 'US/Eastern', etc).

I'm not interested in results that differ depending on whether daylight saving is active - 'CET' and 'CEST' and stuff like that won't do it for me. I've dug around `Time` and `TZInfo` but can't seem to find anything fitting.

Any ideas?

EDIT: It turns out Rails has no native way of getting the Olson time zone - one would have to do it in the shell, something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26915292/5685870). Neikos' [suggestion below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34308805/5685870) is shorter but doesn't work for me because my machine is a modified version of CentOS 7 which is stripped of `timedatectl` but is perhaps useful for someone else.

EDIT 2: I ended up calling the following shell script from within ruby:

```
#!/bin/bash

checksum=`md5sum /etc/localtime | cut -d ' ' -f1`
find /usr/share/zoneinfo/ -type f | xargs md5sum 2> /dev/null |
    grep "^$checksum" | sed "s,.*/usr/share/zoneinfo/,," |
    sort -n | head -n1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Local Time Zone in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445336/local-time-zone-in-ruby)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on CentOS 7 you could use something akin to `timedatectl | grep Time zone` and parse the timezone out of that.

This is obviously not portable to non-systemd systems.

As a not so pretty oneliner:

```
`timedatectl | grep "Time zone"`.split(/:|\(/)[1].strip
```